# Using web3.eth.estimateGas cause "gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction"

Tags: solidity, web3js

In solidity code I have function `addPhase` and it works well. The code  below also works well

```
for (let j = 0; j < companies[i].phases.length; j++) {
    transactions.push(
        this.contract.addPhase(
            companies[i].phases[j].start_time,
            companies[i].phases[j].prices_in_wei,
            companies[i].phases[j].prices_in_wei_ends,
            companies[i].phases[j].tokens_count,
            companies[i].phases[j].min_tokens_to_sell,
            Web3Helpers.sender_envelope(sender,10000000000)));
}
```

But if I try to estimate gas consumption

```
for (let j = 0; j < companies[i].phases.length; j++) {
    let call_data_phase = this.contract.addPhase.getData(
        companies[i].phases[j].start_time,
        companies[i].phases[j].prices_in_wei,
        companies[i].phases[j].prices_in_wei_ends,
        companies[i].phases[j].tokens_count,
        companies[i].phases[j].min_tokens_to_sell
    );
    let gas_needed_phase = Web3Helpers.web3.eth.estimateGas({
        data: call_data_phase,
        to: this.contract.address,
        from: sender
    });
    console.log("Gas estimation=" + gas_needed_phase);

    transactions.push(
        this.contract.addPhase(
            companies[i].phases[j].start_time,
            companies[i].phases[j].prices_in_wei,
            companies[i].phases[j].prices_in_wei_ends,
            companies[i].phases[j].tokens_count,
            companies[i].phases[j].min_tokens_to_sell,
            Web3Helpers.sender_envelope(sender,10000000000)));
}
```

I get error **gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction**. I use similar code for other functions and gas estimation works well.

Has anybody seen something like this and what could it be?

Comment: This error also make from the contract if "require" option in the function that was estimated returns "false". I did get this error by it. for example (Solidity): require(uint8(block_num) == current_blk + 1); Code above returned false after execute and sended me that error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After looking at the [source code for this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/accounts/abi/bind/backends/simulated.go), you'll notice that it's failing because the gas allowance does not result in an executable transaction. `EstimateGas` function executes the requested code against the currently pending block/state and returns the used amount of gas (or error in your case). But, it can also fail if the transaction is ill-formed.

```
var errGasEstimationFailed = errors.New("gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction")

// Reject the transaction as invalid if it still fails at the highest allowance
if hi == cap {
    if !executable(hi) {
        return nil, errGasEstimationFailed
    }
}
```

---

It looks like you may be incorrectly passing arguments to `getData` and thus in turn `estimateGas`.

> Update: Please try below code.

```
let call_data_phase = this.contract.addPhase.getData(
        companies[i].phases[j].start_time,
        companies[i].phases[j].prices_in_wei,
        companies[i].phases[j].prices_in_wei_ends,
        companies[i].phases[j].tokens_count,
        companies[i].phases[j].min_tokens_to_sell,
        {from: sender, gas: 10000000000}

    );
```

`web3.eth.estimateGas({data: call_data_phase, from: sender})`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please explain how not to "using call_data_phase to pass all params at once and split out into separate callObjects"

Comment: @AlexeyBarsuk please try my proposed solution. I've updated answer to be more clear

Comment: You’re welcome @AlexeyBarsuk