# Executing estimateGas() return meta mask error?

Tags: web3js

Running the following line of code to get the Estimated Gas, returns some errors [more here](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/4564)

**Solidity**

```
function deposit() public payable {
    store.deposit();
}
```

**JS**

```
const deposit = await contract.methods.deposit()
const gas = await deposit.estimateGas({from: myAddress, value: value})
```

[Here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32123/using-web3-eth-estimategas-cause-gas-required-exceeds-allowance-or-always-faili) you can see someone had similar issue by incorrectly passing arguments, this is not true in my case sense I don't pass anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research I realised there is a error in my solidity code,

Not sure exactly how but apparently some errors getting compiled in solidity giving the impression that the problem is with web3 or meta mask.